# How to get the result for the same user?

Tags: sql, database

I want to get the users who confirm twice for the same document.

**My table is like this**:

```
emp_num -- serial -- doc_num
```

**I want to get result like this**:

```
344 -- 11 -- 3
344 -- 12 -- 3
344 -- 13 -- 3
756 -- 45 -- 16
756 -- 48 -- 16
```

and so on.

How can I do this?

---

My result :

```
344 -- 11 -- 3
344 -- 12 -- 3
344 -- 13 -- 3
756 -- 45 -- 16
756 -- 48 -- 16
333 -- 56 -- 77
564 -- 79 -- 87
564 -- 80 -- 87
```

---

i don't want the emp_num = 333 included in the result because it's a one record.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Could u let me clarify what u don't get in this Q?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "confirm"; it is not clear what the `serial` column's semantics are in your schema; it is not clear why `SELECT emp_num, serial, doc_num FROM whatever` is insufficient for you, as it matches your required result.

Comment: okay .Don't care about the meaning of confirm , just i want result like the above where the same user have more than one record in the same document(doc_num)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack over flow "works best" if an attempt is shown in the post. This shows effort, allows explanation of refinements/errors, and helps to clarify intent ..

In any case, this is likely close to what is desired:

```
 select t1.*
 from theTable t1
 join theTable t2
 on t1.emp_num = t2.emp_num     -- look at records for same employee
   and t1.doc_num = t2.doc_num  -- that have the same document num
   and t1.serial <> t2.serial   -- but have a different "serial"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your notes , I'll take in my considerations in next questions . but i wanna just those users which have more than one record . 

this query brings also the users which has just one record for the same document.

Comment: @just_name It should do no such thing *given the sample data*. The `t1.serial <> t2.serial` should prevent that. In any case, consider this a freebie "start": add it to the original post, and show what output it generates along with what output is desired ..

Comment: I updated my question with a sample of my result .Could u check it please ?

Answer (score 1):

Most databases have something called windows or analytic functions.  One of these will count the number of records in a group.  The best way to do this query is:

```
select emp_num, serial, doc_num
from (select emp_num, serial, doc_num,
             count(*) over (partition by emp_num) as totalcount
      from t
     )
where totalcount > 1
```

You can put however many fields you want in the partition statement.  It seems that you only want to count the total number of records by employee.